# How to Check if an android View has not been touched at all

Tags: java, android, android-activity, boolean, android-canvas

Is there a prewritten boolean that checks if the screen has not been touched and gets called if the screen hasn't been touched. I know there is public boolean onTouchEvent, but is there something that checks the opposite?

Comment: i guess thats why a vote down is an opinion

Comment: If `onTouchEvent` hasn't been called, then you know there hasn't been a touch event... So set a booleen to true in this method.  If it's false, you know that method hasn't been executed.......?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty certain there is no such thing.  Particularly if you want to know if the "screen" has not been touched.  Your question title says "view" and the question says "screen".  If you want to know whether a view has been touched, what's wrong with tracking it with a listener?

Answer (score 0):

No there isn't but you can assume an Activity or Fragment has not been touched until a touch event is handled.